# how to change the host type for a 'Canadian cross' compilation of GCC with crosstool-NG

Tags: linux, gcc, cross-compiling, embedded-linux, crosstool-ng

I've installed crosstool-NG and built GCC on a host+build x86 machine that targets arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi.  I've then used arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-gcc to compile a program that ran well on my ARM board.

I'm wanting to now build GCC, targeting ARM to be hosted on ARM.  I believe the lingo is

```
build=i486-pc-linux-gnu
target=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-gcc
host=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-gcc
```

How do I do this?  do I run ./configure for crosstool-NG passing --host=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-gcc?

or do I change the environment variables for CC/etc?

Comment: I believe it is the right approach. What did you try, and what does not work? Perhaps `gcc-help@gcc.gnu.org` is a better place to ask.

Comment: mostly I'm lacking confidence and am seeking reassurance that I'm on the correct path :)

I tried this but crosstool-ng-1.14.1 is giving an error saying that the curses header couldnt be found.  Since it worked very well for making a standard cross compiler I assumed I was doing something incorrectly

Comment: It looks right to me. Note that that's not a *Canadian Cross*: that's a *Cross-Native* build. A Canadian Cross would have all three platforms different. E.g. a good way to build for Windows is to use build=i686-pc-liunx-gnu host=i686-mingw32 target=arm-unknown-linux-gnu

Answer (score 1):

You do this with a *.config* file.  I think samples with a comma in the name are good ones to look at. The main difference is that you must run *ct-ng* multiple times to create several cross compilers.

*ct-ng* has under went some changes in *Canadian crosses* lately.  However, you will probably need to re-use your original cross compiler that runs on the PC.  The reason is that a compiler will include libraries compiled for the *ARM* and you need to generate these libraries on your PC.  Generally, ensure that the iX86-host+ARM-target compiler is on your path.  Then you must set the *host tuple* or prefix for this tool chain in the *toolchain* menu.  You need set the *build tuple* to the same compiler.

> ct-ng help | grep variables

This gives a directory with a bunch of *text* files that you can *grep* for hints.

See *6 - Toolchain types.txt* for example.  *Cross-native* or *Canadian-cross* really doesn't matter, in terms of complexity of building.  You need only one intermediate for *Cross native*, but you need two intermediate compilers for a *Canadian cross*.

**Edit:** [Ct-ng's *How a compiler is constructed*](http://crosstool-ng.org/hg/crosstool-ng/file/tip/docs/9%20-%20How%20is%20a%20toolchain%20constructed.txt) has some information on all the happening.

Comment: The 'git' link is [Ct-ng's How a compiler is constructed](http://crosstool-ng.org/git/crosstool-ng/plain/docs/6%20-%20Toolchain%20types.txt) which is probably longer term, since the answer was written.